# onclick="" javascript inline issue

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have found a great pure javascript code for smooth scrolling function, but i dont know how to make it work whit the onclick inline function.
im sure its something simple, but a am very weak at javascript...

```
<div class="navbar">
  <button type="button" id="clickme">scroll whit class</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="smoothScroll(third)" >not working yet</button>
 </div>

<div class="third" id="third">The start of the red section!</div>
```

and the smoothScroll function javascript:

```
var targetY;

document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', function() {

    smoothScroll(document.getElementById('third'));
});

window.smoothScroll = function(target) {

    var scrollContainer = target;

    headerSpace();

    do {
    scrollContainer = scrollContainer.parentNode;
    if (!scrollContainer) return;
    scrollContainer.scrollTop += 1;
    }
    while (scrollContainer.scrollTop == 0);

    do {
    if (target == scrollContainer) break;
    targetY += target.offsetTop;
    }
    while (target = target.offsetParent);

    scroll = function(c, a, b, i) {

        i++; if (i > 30) return;
        c.scrollTop = a + (b - a) / 30 * i;
        setTimeout(function() {scroll(c, a, b, i); }, 20);
    }

    scroll(scrollContainer, scrollContainer.scrollTop, targetY, 0);
}

function headerSpace() {

    var header = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar');
    targetY = -header[0].clientHeight;
}
```

As you see there is all ready getElement by id, but i want to remove it and make it working only whit inline

```
onclick="smoothScroll(second)"
onclick="smoothScroll(third)"
onclick="smoothScroll(fourth)"
```

and so on....
Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poqzb33o/2/)

Comment: Add `document.getElementById` to `smoothScroll` and use `onclick="smoothScroll('second')"`

Comment: You **want** to use `onclick` attributes? Stop wanting that. This isn't 1997. They have exciting gotchas and their use is not considered a best practice.

Comment: Its not if i want or not, in my case i have to use onclick. Thank you for your opinion but you are not helping at all.

Comment: working fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/8ch4bon9/

Comment: Your Fiddle code is different than the code posted in your question. What is the correct code to use ? Can you please update your question if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var scrollContainer = document.getElementById(target);
target = document.getElementById(target);
```

then in your html

```
<button type="button" onclick="smoothScroll('third')" id="clickme">scroll whit onclick=""</button>
```

working fiddler
https://jsfiddle.net/8ch4bon9/1

Answer (score 0):

try using this one will help you with smooth scrolling and this is too easy to use

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

all what you need is to have a link

```
<a href="#third">not working yet</a>
<div id="third"></div>
```

this will work smoothly with you on any link binded to any div (href (for link) & id (for the div)) be careful for these 2 attributes and this will work fine

also you can find here in the following link a demo examle will explain to you more

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Answer (score 0):

Your Fiddle is different that the code provided in your question. Assuming your Fiddle is the most recent version, it does not work because you have two buttons with the same id which is not valid according to the HTML specification

```
<button type="button" id="clickme">scroll whit class</button>
<button type="button" id="clickme">scroll whit onclick=""</button>
```

As a result the event listener is only added to the first button as `getElementById` only returns one element:

```
document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', function() {
```

You can solve this by adding a different id to the second button:

```
<button type="button" id="clickme">scroll whit class</button>
<button type="button" id="clickme1">scroll whit onclick=""</button>
```

And add a second listener:

```
function scrollDiv() 
{
    var header = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar');
    aim = -header[0].clientHeight;
    initial = Date.now();

    smoothScroll(document.getElementById('third'));
}

document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', scrollDiv)
document.getElementById('clickme1').addEventListener('click', scrollDiv)
```

Or somewhat cleaner, you could add a class to the buttons and iterate over the result of `document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: this has nothing to do with the requested problem

Comment: The posted Fiddle is different than the question. As the Fiddle incorporates feedback from some of the comments. it seems more recent, I will ask the poster to clarify

Comment: Well the topic title mentions INLINE. Javascript addEventListener is not inline